# Refresh content of a Div

Tags: php, jquery, html, slideshow

I have read through multiple posts regarding reloading the content of a div through the use of Jquery. I have a Dashboard with multiple floating divs that rotates data calculated in php scripts.

ie. i have a php script that calculates data and i include this in a div which then scrolls through the content (see below code)

The problem i have with the code examples available online is that it doesnt show my php content.

How can i go about reloading the php pages in the div and still keep my slideshow going?

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="topdiv_1">
    <div id="topdiv_1_slideshow">
        <div align="center">
            <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px" style="padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 50px;">
            <h1 style="font-size: 90px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold"><?php include_once('topdiv_1_stat1.php') ?></h1>
            <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold">Project Hours Total</h6>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px"
                 style="padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 50px;">

            <h1 style="font-size: 90px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold"><?php include_once('topdiv_1_stat2.php') ?></h1>
            <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold">Project Hours System Center</h6>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px"
                 style="padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 50px;">

            <h1 style="font-size: 90px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold"><?php include_once('topdiv_1_stat3.php') ?></h1>
            <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold">Project Hours Service Center</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I have tried adding this code to the div but now it throws away the formatting of the returned value:

```
<div id="topdiv_1_slideshow">
        <div align="center" id="1">
            <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px" style="padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 50px;">
            <h1 style="font-size: 90px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold"><?php /*include_once('topdiv_1_stat1.php') */?>
                <script>
                    $(function(){
                    $("#1").load("topdiv_1_stat1.php");
                    });
                </script>

                </h1>
            <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold">Project Hours Total</h6>
        </div>
```

Comment: Tried using ajax?

Comment: Added an update to my original question @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: can you show us the output of the "topdiv_1_stat1.php" script?

Comment: @JasperZelf topdiv_1_stat1.php returns a value '825' but the font styling is missing, it seems if i load the page via JS it doesnot apply the styling, but when i load the page via `<?php include_once('topdiv_1_stat1.php'); ?>` then the styling applies properly without issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
$("#1").load("topdiv_1_stat1.php");
```

will load the raw output of the topdiv_1_stat1.php script.

That means that links to stylesheets in that response will not be loaded as they would when you open the page in your browser.

Make sure your script "topdiv_1_stat1.php"only returns the html that you want in the #1 div.

Comment: How will i get the styling to apply to the output of the script? when i load it with `<?php include_once('topdiv_1_stat1.php'); ?>` then the styling applies with no issue

Comment: Looking at your code, you replace the content of your entire <div align="center" id="1"> element.

Since you have styling in there, it will be replaced by the output of the php script. So after the `load()` is done your code will look like this:

` <div align="center" id="1">825</div>`

You'll propably only want to replace the contents of the H1 tag inside `<div id="1">`. 

Try this:

`$("#1 h1").load("topdiv_1_stat1.php");`

Comment: Thanks i managed to fix it by using your advice! `<h1 style="font-size: 90px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold">
                    <div id="1">
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                setInterval(function() {
                                    $("#1").load("topdiv_1_stat1.php");
                                }, 3000);
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </h1>`

Comment: Good to see you got it working. 
Please note that you do not have to put your script inside the `<h1>` and `<div>` tags like you would do using PHP. 

PHP renders it's output straight intp the HTML on the spot where you place it. The Javascript code we're using now injects it after the HTML is done loading. '$("#1")' means you're targeting the element with ID=1. 

Best practice is to place the Javascript (and styling) in a different file

Answer (score 0):

You can call a php script with Ajax, get the datas and show all the datas returned by the PHP script in the DOM element you want, that will refresh it with fresh datas.

But you can't refresh only a part of your page without javascript.